# how can I call `useQuery` from react-query in conditionally

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-query

I have 3 functions `shouldCallApi` return true or false that decide if  `useApiCall` should trigger
if yes, `useSecondApiCall` will return some data and pass into query for `useApiCall` to build its query then return the response
no problem for me to call `useApiCall` under component level however how can I make sure `useApiCall` only trigger when `shouldCallApi` return as true?

```
export function shouldCallApi(): boolean {
  ...
}

export function useApiCall(
  parameter, 
  shouldExecuteQuery = true
  ) {
  const [query] = useDebounce(parameter, 350);
  const {data} = useSecondApiCall(query);
  const {totalNumber} = data?.number || {};
   
   const query = useQuery<APIhCreateMutation, Error>(
     [{query: apihCreateGQL, variables: {...query, count: totalNumber}}],
     async () => {
       const result: APIhCreateMutation= await ucFetch(apiUrl, {
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
         body: JSON.stringify({
           query: apiCreateGQL,
           variables: {...query, count: totalNumber},
         }),
       });
       return result;
     },
     {refetchOnWindowFocus: false, enabled: shouldExecuteQuery, keepPreviousData: true}
   );
   return query;
}
export default function App() {
const query = useSelector((state) => state.query);
 const {response} =useApiCall(query) 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Edit to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are using `shouldExecuteQuery`. Why not do something like `, enabled: shouldCallApi()` in your `useQuery` options?

Comment: I don't know if switching enabled from false to true triggers a `refetch` but if it doesn't, just set enabled to false and call the `refetch` function in a `useEffect` that triggers upon `shouldExecuteQuery`

Comment: @SILENT no way for me to use useEffect to triggers the `useApiCall` because it breaks the react policy....that useQuery cannot be executing under useEffect if that is not you mean

Comment: @jacobcan118 I added an answer with an example

Answer (score 2):

> how can I make sure useApiCall only trigger when shouldCallApi return as true?

That is what the `enabled` option is for, which you are already using in your example - but it is not clear to me how `shouldExecuteQuery` and `shouldCallApi` play together?

As long as enabled is `false`, the query will "pause". If you have no data yet, it will be in `idle` state. When enabled transitions from `false` to `true`, an automatic refetch will be triggered.

So really, it's just:

```
useQuery(queryKey, queryFn, { enabled: shouldCallApi() }
```

Comment: it seems some conflict with my implementation. `useQuery` under `useApiCall` that exist under component level. but I should like `useApiCall` trigger whenever `shouldCallApi() ` return as true. if i just place `shouldCallApi()` as enabled then `useApiCall` will only be triggered when component render and also `shouldCallApi()`?